Shipout box to tempfile
I currently have a Python script which (through ImageMagick) makes a PDF appear photocopied. I am trying to migrate this process to a LaTeX class—for fun, to see what is possible in LaTeX.
It seems that one way this could work is to intercept \shipout with some external calls to modify the output PDF. Using atbegshi for intercepting shipout, the procedure would look like

Generate a page worth of LaTeX code.
AtBeginShipout, write the contents of AtBeginShipoutBox (i.e., \Box255) to a temporary file, temppage.tex.
Call pdftex on the temporary file and distort the PDF via ImageMagick to a temporary file temppage.png.
Instead of shipping out the contents of AtBeginShipoutBox, shipout a box containing \includegraphics{temppage.png}.

When write18 is enabled, steps (3) and (4) seem mostly straightforward. This leaves step (2).
Is it possible to explicitly shipout a box to a temporary PDF? If that is not possible, perhaps there is a reliable way to echo the raw TeX of a box to a tempfile to be compiled later?
The end goal is a LaTeX class which need not call another script to make the output PDF look photocopied.

tex can only write one pdf not one per shipout and there is no way in general to construct tex that would generate a box (so your step 2, in particular is not possible in general).  Depending on what exactly you mean by "look photocopied" you may be able to get the effect you want by chhosing suitable font features in advance of typesetting

a box does not contain tex code, it contains an internal representation of typeset output.

Welcome! What is pdfTeX supposed to do in 2 exactly? Setting the question of whether it is possible aside, I'm confused by how it is supposed to work. What's the advantage of typesetting the page twice? Why not run whatever distortion on the page as-is? Why typeset it a second time first?

It's possible to extract certain pages of a PDF at the beginning of the document and then to include the extracted pages later as external images. Given that, I assume it is possible to extract all pages of a PDF at the beginning of the document, do something with them and then include them (or their descendants) later as external images. At the limit, I guess you could replace every page of the original PDF in this way. If you used e.g. pdfpages for the re-inclusion, the processed images would constitute the pages of the document after the second compilation. Sort of an extreme memoize?
